# exception Dl.DL_error : undefined symbol: SDL_GetError

Tags: binding, ocaml, sdl-2

So, I wanted to use `Tsdl` and here's what I did :

- I couldn't find `SDL 2.0.5` with `apt-get` so I downloaded it, `./configure && make && sudo make install`
- `opam install tsdl`
- Then I created a file `main.ml` (given as an example on [tsdl website](http://erratique.ch/software/tsdl/doc/Tsdl.html#examples)) :

  ```
  open Tsdl
  open Result

  let main () = match Sdl.init Sdl.Init.video with
    | Error (`Msg e) -> Sdl.log "Init error: %s" e; exit 1
    | Ok () ->
      match Sdl.create_window ~w:640 ~h:480 "SDL OpenGL" Sdl.Window.opengl with
       | Error (`Msg e) -> Sdl.log "Create window error: %s" e; exit 1
       | Ok w ->
         Sdl.delay 3000l;
         Sdl.destroy_window w;
         Sdl.quit ();
         exit 0

  let () = main ()
  ```
- `ocamlfind ocamlopt -package tsdl -linkpkg -o main.native main.ml`

It works and now comes my problem :

```
./main.native
Fatal error: exception Dl.DL_error("./main.native: undefined symbol: SDL_GetError")
```

Did I do something wrong or do I need to tell explicitly where my SDL2 lib is or something else ?

---

Update :

```
> ocamlobjinfo $(opam config var tsdl:lib)/tsdl.cmxa | grep Extra
Extra C object files: -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2 -ltsdl
Extra C options:

> sdl2-config --libs
-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2
```

---

Update 2 :

```
> ldd ./main.native 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff1f4c1000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f4aff55e000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4aff255000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4aff050000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4afec87000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055dc05e17000)
```

---

Update 3

```
lhooq@lhooq ~/tsdl $ ocamlfind ocamlopt -cclib -lSDL2 -package tsdl -linkpkg -o min.native min.ml -verbose

Effective set of compiler predicates: pkg_result,pkg_unix,pkg_bigarray,pkg_str,pkg_bytes,pkg_ctypes,pkg_ctypes.foreign.base,pkg_ctypes.foreign.unthreaded,pkg_ctypes.foreign,pkg_tsdl,autolink,native
+ ocamlopt.opt -o min.native -verbose -I /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/result -I /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/bytes -I /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes -I /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/tsdl /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/result/result.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/unix.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/bigarray.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/str.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes-foreign-base.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes-foreign-unthreaded.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/tsdl/tsdl.cmxa -cclib -lSDL2 min.ml
+ as -o 'min.o' '/tmp/camlasm9ab424.s'
+ as -o '/tmp/camlstartupe796c9.o' '/tmp/camlstartup4a1081.s'
+ gcc -o 'min.native'   '-L/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/result' '-L/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/bytes' '-L/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes' '-L/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/tsdl' '-L/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml'  '/tmp/camlstartupe796c9.o' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/std_exit.o' 'min.o' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/tsdl/tsdl.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes-foreign-unthreaded.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes-foreign-base.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/str.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/bigarray.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/unix.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/result/result.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/stdlib.a' '-L/usr/local/lib' '-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib' '-Wl,--enable-new-dtags' '-lSDL2' '-ltsdl' '-Wl,--no-as-needed' '-lffi' '-lctypes-foreign-base_stubs' '-Wl,--no-as-needed' '-lffi' '-lctypes_stubs' '-Wl,--no-as-needed' '-lcamlstr' '-lbigarray' '-lunix' '-lSDL2' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/libasmrun.a' -lm  -ldl

lhooq@lhooq ~/tsdl $ ocamlfind ocamlopt -package tsdl -linkpkg -o min.native min.ml -verbose

Effective set of compiler predicates: pkg_result,pkg_unix,pkg_bigarray,pkg_str,pkg_bytes,pkg_ctypes,pkg_ctypes.foreign.base,pkg_ctypes.foreign.unthreaded,pkg_ctypes.foreign,pkg_tsdl,autolink,native
+ ocamlopt.opt -o min.native -verbose -I /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/result -I /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/bytes -I /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes -I /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/tsdl /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/result/result.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/unix.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/bigarray.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/str.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes-foreign-base.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes-foreign-unthreaded.cmxa /home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/tsdl/tsdl.cmxa min.ml
+ as -o 'min.o' '/tmp/camlasm201bd8.s'
+ as -o '/tmp/camlstartup7113e2.o' '/tmp/camlstartup4724f2.s'
+ gcc -o 'min.native'   '-L/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/result' '-L/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/bytes' '-L/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes' '-L/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/tsdl' '-L/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml'  '/tmp/camlstartup7113e2.o' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/std_exit.o' 'min.o' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/tsdl/tsdl.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes-foreign-unthreaded.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes-foreign-base.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ctypes/ctypes.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/str.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/bigarray.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/unix.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/result/result.a' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/stdlib.a' '-L/usr/local/lib' '-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib' '-Wl,--enable-new-dtags' '-lSDL2' '-ltsdl' '-Wl,--no-as-needed' '-lffi' '-lctypes-foreign-base_stubs' '-Wl,--no-as-needed' '-lffi' '-lctypes_stubs' '-Wl,--no-as-needed' '-lcamlstr' '-lbigarray' '-lunix' '/home/lhooq/.opam/4.04.0/lib/ocaml/libasmrun.a' -lm  -ldl
```

Comment: The `apt` package name is `libsdl2-dev`.

Comment: Yes, that I know, but the version is `2.0.4`.

Comment: It looks like the sdl lib cannot be found. Could you please report the output of: `ocamlobjinfo $(opam config var tsdl:lib)/tsdl.cmxa | grep Extra` and `sdl2-config --libs`

Comment: Ah, Debian repositories strike again. What did `make install` provide you with? A bunch of `.so` files?

Comment: Are you sure that `/usr/local/lib` is in the `rpath` ? Could you also check that `/usr/local/lib/libSDL2.so` exists. And does it maybe work by invoking `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./main.native` ?

Comment: Another step would be to first make the minimal C example [here](https://github.com/dbuenzli/tsdl/blob/master/test/minc.c) work. So that we know the install works at least for C.

Comment: So : `minc.c`, no problem, I can compile and launch it and it creates an empty window then stops.

Comment: I have `/usr/local/lib/libSDL2.so`. It doesn't work by invoking `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./main.native` (same error). And, shame on me but how do I know if `/usr/local/lib` is in the `rpath` ?

Comment: I don't know either, but this website suggests something like `objdump -x ./main.native | grep RPATH` but it is odd anyways that it doesn't work with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: If I write `objdump -x ./main.native | grep PATH` (instead of  `grep RPATH`) I have this line : `RUNPATH /usr/local/lib`.

Comment: What does `ldd ./main.native` say ?

Comment: Strange that `libSDL2` is not mentioned.

Comment: Try to compile with `ocamlfind ocamlopt -cclib -lSDL2 -package tsdl -linkpkg -o main.native min.ml` (but then the Extra flags of the cmxa should have added that)

Comment: Also invoking the compilation line with `-verbose` might provide useful information.

Comment: Yes, it works like this. Do you know what is going wrong in the first compilation directive ?

Comment: No it's very strange, `ocamlobjinfo` told us that the link flags are correctly specified, so this `-cclib` should not be needed. Could you diff the two different compilation lines invoked with `-verbose`.

Comment: Well, it looks that there's just `-cclib -lSDL2` added in the compilation directive (so, the same `.cmxa` are loaded. And in the `gcc` directive I have `'-lSDL2'`.

Comment: So without the `-cclib`, `-lSDL2` is not added in the gcc invocation ? This is very strange since all the flags mentioned in the `Extra C object files:`  of the `cmxa` should be added at link time by the ocaml compilers.

Comment: Yes, without `-cclib` I don't have `-lSDL2` in the `gcc` invocation. Will this remain a mystery ? ;-)

Comment: Well I don't like this. Could you please post both verbose invocations somewhere ?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I just updated my question with the verbose invocations and their result.

Comment: FWIW I'm having the same issue. Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: `sdl2-config --libs`: -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL2

Comment: `ocamlobjinfo $(opam config var tsdl:lib)/tsdl.cmxa | grep Extra`: Extra C object files: -lSDL2 -ltsdl

Comment: @DanielBünzli let me know if you want to investigate in realtime through IRC or discord or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a minor issue in tsdl, see this for more information: https://github.com/dbuenzli/tsdl/issues/38

It is fixed in master. As the author suggests you can (for now) do this as a temporary fix:

`opam pin add tsdl --dev`

EDIT: as indicated by @dbuenzli below this is fixed in 0.9.4 which is on its way to opam.

Comment: Thanks for the help @esl. Could you please add that this is fixed in 0.9.4 which is on its way to the opam repo https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/pull/9770 (it may take a bit of time to merge as I'm cleaning a bit stuff around the tsdl package depext at the same time)